# rails, given a HTML string from a WYSIWYG - how to get just text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a large HTML string from a WYSIWYG and want to show a truncates string of just text, no html or html tags. Is there any way to do this built into rails or do I need a gsub to get rid of all html brackets?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails already includes some powerful [sanitization helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html).

```
string = '<span id="span_is"><br><br><u><i>Hi</i></u></span>'
strip_tags(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon how complex your HTML is, but you could certainly use **[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)** and **XPath** to query the text that you want from the HTML. It depends upon how much you want to parse, and whether it justifies an extra library to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A parser can do it but would be overkill if you have simple HTML to present. Something like [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) or [sanitize](http://wonko.com/post/sanitize) could strip all the tags using Nokogiri to parse the HTML then strip out the tags, leaving you with the text.

```
require 'sanitize'

html = '<html><body>Jackdaws love my giant sphinx of quartz.</body></html>'
puts Sanitize.clean(html)
# >> Jackdaws love my giant sphinx of quartz.
```

I think loofah is more capable than sanitize, but if all you want to do is toss tags away sanitize might be the way to go.